# ggplot2 - How to plot column with multiple dtypes?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot some data relating to carbon storage using ggplot2 in R. I am able to plot each data feature against the target variable 'carbon', but when I do so there are so many ticks on the x axis that the numbers become illegible.

The issue lies in the `values` column having a mix of dtypes. Here is an example of my data:

```
     carbon     variable  value
1  9.095765            x 266500
2 10.704285   soil_class      D
3 10.731987            y     20
4  9.365821        slope   -134
...
```

See my code and output:

```r
CarbonData <- melt(df, id.vars = 'carbon')

features_to_plot <- c("x", "y", "slope", "spring_tas30s","summer_tas30s","winter_tas30s","precip30s","summer_sunlight30s","vpd_30s","soil_class")

ggplot(CarbonData[CarbonData$variable %in% features_to_plot, ]) +
  geom_point(aes(x=value, y=carbon, colour=variable))+
  geom_smooth(aes(x=value, y=carbon, colour=variable), method = lm)+
  facet_wrap(~variable, scales="free")+
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

Which generates this plot:
[image: THIS PLOT]
note the 'blurring' of the x ticks due to having so many values included.

I am trying to make it so that there are only 4 ticks on the x axis for each individual plot, but run into an error due to the `soil_class` entries in the `variable` column having discrete string values `"A", "B", "C", "D"`, as opposed to the rest of the variables which have numeric values. See below:

When running:

```r
ggplot(CarbonData[CarbonData$variable %in% features_to_plot, ]) +
  geom_point(aes(x=value, y=carbon, colour=variable))+
  geom_smooth(aes(x=value, y=carbon, colour=variable), method = lm)+
  facet_wrap(~variable, scales="free")+
  theme(legend.position = "none")+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(min(CarbonData$value), max(CarbonData$value), length.out = 4))
```

I get this error:

```r
Error in seq.default(min(CarbonData$value), max(CarbonData$value), length.out = 5) : 
  'to' must be a finite number
```

This is the structure of the subset of CarbonData I am plotting:

```
>dput(CarbonData[1:10, ])

structure(list(carbon = c(9.09576541437457, 10.7042846612418, 
10.7319869644681, 9.36582055906706, 10.8341206905396, 10.5163368216521, 
10.2719884681734, 9.19142871209431, 9.55741483557631, 9.75877142971814
), variable = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L), levels = c("x", "y", "slope", "spring_tas40s", "spring_tas30s", 
"spring_tas20s", "summer_tas40s", "summer_tas30s", "summer_tas20s", 
"summer_tasmax40s", "summer_tasmax30s", "summer_tasmax20s", "winter_tasmin40s", 
"winter_tasmin30s", "winter_tasmin20s", "precip40s", "precip30s", 
"precip20s", "summer_sunlight40s", "summer_sunlight30s", "summer_sunlight20s", 
"vpd_40s", "vpd_30s", "vpd_20s", "soil_class"), class = "factor"), 
    value = c("266500", "264500", "265500", "248500", "302500", 
    "292500", "314500", "321500", "323500", "322500")), row.names = c(NA, 
10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

I have achieved what I wanted by encoding the `soil_class` string values into numeric values.

This code:

```r
CarbonData <- melt(df, id.vars = 'carbon')

CarbonData <- CarbonData %>%
  mutate(value = ifelse(value %in% c("A", "B", "C", "D"), match(value, c("A", "B", "C", "D")), as.numeric(value)))

features_to_plot <- c("x", "y", "slope", "spring_tas30s","summer_tas30s","winter_tas30s","precip30s","summer_sunlight30s","vpd_30s","soil_class")

ggplot(CarbonData[CarbonData$variable %in% features_to_plot, ]) +
  geom_point(aes(x=value, y=carbon, colour=variable)) +
  facet_wrap(~variable, scales="free")+
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

Achieves [the desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f88Xp.png), but does not solve the question.

Comment: Usually that means your `x` should be numeric, but are stored as `character` or `factor` class. If you share a little bit of data we with `dput()`, we can look at your data structure and reproduce it and help solve the problem.

Comment: `dput(CarbonData[1:10, ])` will make copy/pasteable R code to reproduce the first 10 rows of your data. Please edit that into your question.

Comment: But yeah, you can't really mix discrete and numeric data in one column. You may need a different approach to structuring your data. Keeping your data in a wide format, using a loop to generate individual plots, and then combining them with `grid.arrange` or `patchwork` might be a better choice.

Comment: Thanks @GregorThomas , I have added a bit more information. I've tried patchwork but still ran into the same error due to the datatype. I'll have a go at grid.arrange

Comment: Patchwork and grid arrange are just methods to combine the plots--they won't help you make the plots. As I said, you'll want to have your data in a wide format, make sure the data types are correct for each column, then generate the plots in a loop.

Comment: Also, please use `dput()` for sharing data as requested. The copy/paste you did does not include any info about the column classes. In what you shared, the `value` column *appears* to be `numeric`, but from your plots we can tell it is either `character` or `factor`. This is a major reason why sharing with `dput()` which includes the column classes, is much better.

Comment: So, did you data start in this long format or did you `pivot_longer`/`melt` it?

Comment: @GregorThomas Should be clear now. CarbonData is a melted wide `df`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without your wide data, I've demonstrated on the built-in `diamonds` data how I would approach this (keeping the data in a wide format):

```
library(ggplot2)
df = diamonds

columns_to_plot <- setdiff(names(df), c("price"))
colors = RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(length(columns_to_plot), "Set3") |> setNames(columns_to_plot)
plots_list <- list()

for (column in columns_to_plot) {
  plot <- ggplot(df, aes(x = !!sym(column), y = price)) +
    geom_point(color = colors[column]) +
    labs(title = column) +
    theme_classic() +
    theme(axis.title.y = element_blank())
  if(is.numeric(df[[column]])) {
    plot = plot + geom_smooth(se = FALSE, color = scales::alpha("black", .6))
  } else{
    plot = plot + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = -45, vjust = 0.5, hjust = 0))
  }
  
  plots_list[[column]] <- plot
}
patchwork::wrap_plots(plots_list)
```

[image]

Note that if you have more than 12 plots you won't be able to use `RColorBrewer` palettes, but you can set your own colors or repeat or use a `distiller` palette that interpolates, etc.

Comment: Doesn't explicity answer the question, but does provide a good alternative. Thank you.

Comment: This should illustrate how you can get where you want to go. If you want help with your data, you need to share enough data for it to demonstrate a solution. I'd also challenge the premise of your title: by definition a column in a data frame can only have one `class`, there's no such thing as a column with multiple data types.

Comment: Apologies, maybe I'm confusing my terminology, I'm used to python! Regarding title - I've provided an example of what my data looks like - certainly is stored in a dataframe and contained numerics as well as strings "A", "B", "C", "D". If you can think of something better, feel free to make an edit!

Comment: I thought Python is similar in this (though my Pandas is very rusty, could be wrong). A data frame column can only have one data type/class. If you put `numeric` class and `character` class data in the same column, the numeric data will be converted to `character` class so that information isn't lost irretrievably, but they can all be one class. Notice the difference evident in your `dput`, `carbon = c(9.09576541437457, 10.7042846612418,...` no quotes means that's a regular numeric vector, but `value = c("266500", "264500"...` with quotes means that those are string/`character` class values.

Comment: You can use `str(CarbonData)` to examine the data structure, and you'll see that `carbon` is labeled as `num` for numeric, and `value` is labeled as `chr` for character. So, once you melted your data into a long format and combined columns of different classes into one class, you lost the class information. Columns can only have one dtype, so a "column with multiple dtypes" isn't really a thing.